# React component helpers with devise

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, devise

I'm trying to apply the helper of devise for user signed users (user_signed_in?)

I have this in my index.html.erb

```
<%= react_component('EventApplication', {userSignedIn: user_signed_in?}) %>
```

In my event_application.js.jsx I got this

```
if(this.props.userSignedIn=false) {
      return(............)
}
```

But I need the helper in another component too (event.js.jsx) however it does not work and `userSignedIn` return and undefined value

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: seems to be a typo in your `react_component`, you say `userSignedIn` not `usuarioSignedIn`

Comment: I already change to UserSignedIn and still nothing

Comment: @dbfire: If your intention here is to check whether userSignedIn is true or false Do this `if(this.props.userSignedIn == false or better way this.props.userSignedIn === false)`

Comment: But if I need the same code in another component It does not work. When I debug the code shows me that the userSignedIn = undefined

Comment: @dbfire: still getting `undefined`.